# Question wrongly closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899443/how-can-an-app-without-su-permission-wipe-my-device) was closed as off-topic.

The initial version of the question was worded a little bit differently (and at first sight looked like a question about android-Norton app). It was reformulated and (in my opinion) looks better now.

I think that this question was wrongly closed because it is a perfectly legitimate question that any developer needing to implement a "wipe device" feature may have.

The answer to this question implies knowledge of an *advanced* feature of the android platform and so any average android developer is not aware of it... and will wrongly vote to close as unclear or off-topic.

So, please : reopen it.

---

**EDIT**

I just [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25899443/5) the question, to make it more *programming oriented*. I don't think that I changed the original intent of the OP, but I think that it is more suitable for SO.

Do you think my edit is valid ? Do you think it is still off-topic ?

Comment: While I can see where you're coming from, it reads to me not as a programming question, but as a general question about how Android works and how an app can do this, not about how to do it programmatically.

Comment: @Kendra ok, but the answer is to use a specific android API... and it seems to me that "using an API" is programming.

Comment: I somehow knew you were going to respond that way. Just because the _answer_ says it's because of something implemented programmatically, that doesn't mean it is a question _about programming_. If the OP of the question had asked how _they_ could do the same with their app, that would be a completely different story. Besides that, you only say in your answer that that's what they use, not how to use it or anything like that. Your answer is more an explanation of _how_ instead of _how to programmatically_.

Comment: And although I completely disagree with it, the question has been reopened. So you got your wish.

Comment: While we're here, I offered a small grammar edit on your answer. Feel free to reject if you disagree.

Comment: Thanks, I also improve my answer with more technical details.

Comment: Eh, what for?  Asked and answered.

Answer (score 9):

The question has nothing to do with programming. It is a general computer/device question. It needs to be closed as off topic.

FYI - All software likely uses some kind of library or API, but that does not mean that every question about how or why a piece of software operates the way it does is an appropriate programming question.

Comment: I re-worded the question. Do you still think it is off-topic as it is now ?

Comment: No. Despite the fact that you completely altered the premise of the question, you also now introduced the low quality issue of the question not giving any code or example of what has been tried or looked at.