# Is it OK to delete this SO question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I invested some time in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899443/how-can-an-app-without-su-permission-wipe-a-device) (now deleted).

[image]

The question was badly written in the first place, but it was (in my opinion) interesting as it was about a subject not very often covered in the Android tag. So I started by writing an answer and re-wording a little bit the question.

The question has been closed as off-topic, so I came [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271575/question-wrongly-closed) get the feedback of the meta users to understand why it has been closed and receive good feedback on how improving the question so that it became on-topic.

I edited the question, without modifying the original intent of the OP to make the more 'programming oriented' and on topic (in my opinion).

Despite those efforts, the question remains closed (2 re-open votes only). I was about to giving up, when I saw that the question has been deleted. So I searched for the guidelines related to question deletion :

from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.

and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

> a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted

I think that this specific question is not *extremely* off-topic since it has some upvoted comments claiming that it is *perfectly on-topic*.

Is it very low quality ? Well, it's maybe not the perfect gem, but it is far better than the average question in the android tag.

Does this question add anything to the site ? I think yes because, despite an overall negative score : it has 5(+1) upvotes and most of the down-vote where casted on the first revision of the question , not in it's current state.

So, at this point I still don't understand why the question as been deleted (neither why it is still off-topic). Then I notice that none of the close-voter have an android-bronze-badge (and one of them don't even have [android] in it's tags).

This last detail confort me with the idea that this question should never have been closed, nor deleted.

What do you think ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question wrongly closed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271575/question-wrongly-closed)

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it is duplicate (the question is now deleted) I understood the original close reason, the question has been edited "to fit the rules"... and despite that it is deleted ???

Comment: I think you should read some other *recent* questions that were well-received, and see how you can model your future questions after those.

Comment: That question is not deleted and has no `on-hold` now..

Comment: I was wondering if this would be on the same question or not... Looks like a mod finally stepped in and gave an opinion with an on-hold.

Comment: @Kendra Yes and unfortunately he didn't explain his actions with good argumentation.

Comment: @ben75 I know you really want it to be about programming, especially considering you have an upvoted answer on the question, but the question itself is not asking about programming. It's asking about how an app can do a thing, not how to make their app do something. If it has a place on the SE network, it is not on one of the programming sites. At this point, your answer is a very good answer, in my eyes, and you deserve the rep from it... But not on that question, because that question does not belong here. I see where you're coming from, but a couple different mods have weighed in, (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) and have agreed the question on SO is off-topic for SO. If this does get deleted, by mods or otherwise, and stays that way, try to save your answer for future use, or write a question specifically about programming to self-answer.

Comment: @Kendra I don't really worry about the rep, but I think any further reader having similar question may find it useful. There is also this little sentence : "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question" in all "on hold" questions. That's what I did... but it seems I was wrong (and that's frustrating). Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @ben75 I noticed you did try to accomplish that. But, it still doesn't read as a programming question. On top of that, the OP may not want a programming answer, they may have just wanted to know why the app didn't need their permission to wipe the device. Which is why I suggested a different question that is a programming question: Then you can self-answer, and you're not putting words in the OPs mouth. I fully understand what you're trying to do (and it's great that you're not in it for the rep) and I approve- But you're not quite going about it the best way.